# New Line in iOS UILabel After Special Character

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I need to know how to automatically enter new line in UILabel (just like \n for line break) but based on special character.

For example I have this string on a variable =>
let a = "This is an example of animal : - Cat - Dog - Bird".

Normally, my UILabel text will show like this => "This is an example of animal : - Cat - Dog - Bird".

What I want is UILabel show text like this "This is an example of animal : 

 - Cat 

 - Dog 

 - Bird "

So, after the "-" character, it will make a new line automatically, just like the "\n" in a string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label.text = "This is an example of animal :\n - Cat\n - Dog\n - Bird"
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Set `numberOfLines` to 0. then you can use multiple lines

Or if you want the code to do that for you:

```
let aString = "This is an example of animal : - Cat  - Dog - Bird"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "\n-", options: .literal, range: nil)
label.text = newString
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace "-" with "\n" like below code. It's works in swift4.

```
var tmpStr = "This is an example of animal : - Cat - Dog - Bird".replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "\n-")
yourLabel.text = tmpStr
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Comment: I did not see anything wrong in this answer to give down vote.